# Infragistics UltraWinGrid Columns orientation

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid, column-oriented

This is question is relating to Infragistics UltraWinGrid Columns. [image: Infragistics UltraWinGrid Columns]

I am working with Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v10.3

As you can see in the image, columns are on top and spanning left to right.

Can I show the same data with columns on the left spanning from top to bottom?

Where is the setting?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about Cardview layout mode?
(Image taken from the samples installed)

[image: Infragistics UltraGrid in Cardview mode]

This layout could be activated setting the

```
ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].CardView = True;
```

other properties involved in the appearance of the view are

```
ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].CardSettings.....
```